# Link to a stored procedure result set from a .cshtml page in ASP.Net Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net, t-sql, stored-procedures, razor, razor-pages

I want to see movies of a certain media type (ie DVD, Bluray, VHS), so I have created  stored procedure to do that. This stored procedure returns movies that have an ID associated with the media type. For instance, ID 1 returns DVDs. I have a page for my media type that lists the media (the razor pages automatically created the details page for me after scaffolding).

1. I have the code for my stored procedure below:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Movies.Models
{
    public class MovieDataAccessLayer
    {
        string connectionString = "Server=ServerName;Database=DatabaseMovies;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true";

        public IEnumerable<Movies> MovieByMedia(byte? MediaID)
        {
            List<Movies> lstmovie = new List<Movies>();

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_MovieByMedia", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    Movies movies = new Movies();

                    movies.MovieTitle = rdr["MovieTitle"].ToString();
                    movies.MovieYear = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["MovieYear"]);

                    lstmovie.Add(movies);
                }

                con.Close();

            }
            return lstmovie;
        }

    }
}
```

2. Here is my Media Details .cshtml.cs code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Movies.Models;

namespace Movies.Pages.MediaDetails
{
    public class DetailsModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly Movies.Models.MoviesContext _context;

        public DetailsModel(Movies.Models.MoviesContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public Media Media { get; set; }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(byte? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            Media = await _context.Media.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.MediaTypeID == id);


            if (Media == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return Page();
        }
    }
}
```

3. And here is my .cshtml page

```
@model Movies.Pages.MediaDetails.DetailsModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Details";
}

<h1>Details</h1>

<div>
    <h4>Media</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="row">
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Media.MediaType)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Media.MediaType)
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>
<div>
    <a asp-page="./Edit" asp-route-id="@Model.Media.MediaTypeID">Edit</a> |
    <a asp-page="./Index">Back to List</a>
</div>
```

4. Here is the code for my movie details .cshtml that I tried to connect to my Media .cshtml without success

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Movies.Models;

namespace Movies.Pages.MovieDetails
{
    public class DetailsModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly Movies.Models.MoviesContext _context;

        public DetailsModel(Movies.Models.MoviesContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        MovieDataAccessLayer objmovie = new MovieDataAccessLayer();
        public Movies 
            Movies { get; set; }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(byte id)
        {
            Movies = await _context.Movies.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.MediaTypeID == id);

            if (Movies == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return Page();
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to modify my details page that lists out my media types so that when I click "details" for the respective media type, I can generate the result of my stored procedure for the media type that I click on. For instance, when I click "DVD" my stored procedure is executed to show me only my DVDs. How do I do this? I know that I somehow have to reference to my movie data access layer to execute my SP. Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're `GenreID` as a parameter in `MovieByGenre()` method but you're not using it, is this a typo? Also does `MovieByGenre()` currently return all the movies from the database?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, Izzy. It's a typo. I started doing my procedure with GenreID but that will be a little more complicated so I switched over to MediaID and didn't update this. Sorry for the confusion. It should also be MovieByMedia(). And this procedure returns all movies of a certain mediaID. So, for instance a MediaID of 1 would return all movies that are DVDs.

Comment: But you're not passing the id as a parameter to be used by the sproc so I'm confused whether the filtering is even done or not. Also in your `OnGetAsync` action shouldn't it be `Movies = objmovie.MovieByGenre(id).FirstOrDefault(i => i.MediaTypeID == id);`? Of course if the filtering is done in the database then `FirstOrDefault` is not required here and you will have to create a separate method where you return a single `Movies` object

Comment: That's part of what I don't understand. How and where do I pass the parameter to say "When I click on DVD, pass a parameter of 1 to this stored procedure"? I think I should be doing that on the Media Details .cshtml page but I am not sure. I'm new to .Net and I'm trying to piece it together.

Comment: Would you like to do the filtering in the database or the application? Because you have two ways of overcoming your problem here.

Comment: I'd like to filter in the database, unless the other way is more recommended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code worked for me. Izzy's response was very helpful, but there needed to be some tweaks.

My Data Access Layer

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyMovies.Models
{
    public class MovieByMediaDataAccessLayer
    {
        public List<Movies> GetMovieByMedia(byte? MediaID)
        {
            string connectionString = "Server=Servername;Database=Movies;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true";
            var movies = new Movies();
            using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_MovieByMedia", con))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@MediaID", SqlDbType.TinyInt) { Value = MediaID });
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    con.Open();

                    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        List<Movies> Movies = new List<Movies>();
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            Movies movie = new Movies()
                            {
                                MovieTitle = reader["MovieTitle"].ToString(),
                                MovieYear = Convert.ToInt32(reader["MovieYear"])
                            };
                            Movies.Add(movie);
                        }
                        return Movies;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

My Details class where I return all the movies executed from stored procedure (.cshtml.cs file)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using MyMovies.Models;

namespace MyMovies.Pages.MovieDetails
{
    public class DetailsModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly MyMovies.Models.MyMoviesContext _context;

        public DetailsModel(MyMovies.Models.MyMoviesContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }



        MovieByMediaDataAccessLayer objmovie = new MovieByMediaDataAccessLayer();

        public List<Movies> Movies { get; set; }


        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(byte? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            Movies = objmovie.GetMovieByMedia(id);
            if (Movies == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return Page();
        }
    }
}
```

On my "Details" razor page for Media, I actually just went ahead and posted my movie details, since for each media type I wanted to display all the movies.

```
@page
@model MyMovies.Pages.MovieDetails.DetailsModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Details";
}

<h4>Movies</h4>
<hr />
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Movie Title</th>
            <th>Movie Year</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Movies)
        {
            <tr>
                <td class="col-sm-10">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(Model => item.MovieTitle)
                </td>
                <td class="col-sm-10">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(Model => item.MovieYear)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-page="./Index">Back to List</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments:

You will need to firstly make changes in your stored procedure by introducing a `where` clause and accepting a parameter in.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE usp_MovieByMedia
    @MediaID INT //This is the parameter we will accept in the stored procedure which will be passed via our c# code
    SELECT MovieTitle, MovieYear 
    FROM MOVIES 
    WHERE MediaTypeID = @MediaID   // I'm assuming the names here, change as required
```

Now you want to change your method as follows:

```
public Movies GetMovieByMedia(int MediaID)
{
   string connectionString = "Server=ServerName;Database=DatabaseMovies;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true";
   var movies = new Movies();

   using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
   {
     using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_MovieByMedia", con))
     {
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@MediaID", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = MediaID }); //you was missing this.
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        con.Open();

        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
           if (reader.HasRows)
           {
              movies.MovieTitle = reader["MovieTitle"].ToString();
              movies.MovieYear = Convert.ToInt32(reader["MovieYear"]);
           }
         }
      }
    }
    return movies;
 }
```

This will return you a single Movie object.

Please note I have assumed that your `MediaTypeID` column is of type INT in the db and not of `varbinary(1)/binary(1)`. If this is incorrect change as required.

Now in your `OnGetAsync` action you can do:

```
Movies = objmovie.GetMovieByMedia(id);
```

If you don't want to do the filtering in the database then you can use linq to filter in your application as:

```
Movies = objmovie.GetMovieByMedia(id).FirstOrDefault(i => i.MediaTypeID == id); //this will only work if your method stays with the return type of IEnumerable<Movies>
```

Comment: Izzy, I will try this and see how it works for me. Really appreciate it. I'll be back to update shortly.

Comment: After trying this method, I do have a couple questions. 1. Since I would like to click on the media type (in the media details page), should my Async Action code be written in the MediaDetails.cshtml.cs file? Or should it written in the MovieDetails.cshtml.cs file? 2. The code without Clinq is giving me a warning that it is not synchronous. I'm being prompted to use await, but I don't know if I can use it with the new code/format.

Comment: You want to call it where you will display the movie detail I would assume. Note - your sproc will only return one item if you want to return multiple items then in the where clause make use of `IN`. No you can’t use await with this code if you want to make it asynchronous then look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/asynchronous-programming)

Comment: I am getting the following error, although I know the data is present. InvalidOperationException: Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.

Comment: I tried it usng CLinq and I'm getting a CS1061 error that states that IEnumerable<Movies> does not contain a definition for FirstOrDefault. But outside of that, I'd like to be able to list more than one movie, so FirstOrDefault won't really work for what I want either.